# AC supply to digital output

Tags: arduino, analog, lm78xx

I need to sample 8 power switches connected to 230 Volt supply. I want to record the status of these switch every 10 seconds and send to cloud for which I am using arduino with ethernet shield.

For example if status of switches is as below

On Off on On Off Off Off Off

then output should be a single byte 10110000.

I am a novice in electronic so bare with me if its quite straight forward.

As i want this circuit to be place in box for switch space is a concern.

Also my digital pins on Arduino are already used for other purposes.

One option which I was thinking was to use 8 differnt LM7805 to convert AC to dc from all switches and then use some D to A converter, and feed back this Analog signal to analog pin of Arduino from where I can convert that to byte and send to web.

Please guide if LM7805 will take 220V supply (home supply in India) and if not how that can be managed. Also I think using 8 LM7805 will take lot of space.

Comment: "my digital pins on Arduino are already used for other purposes", this is your main problem. How can you possibly get the information in to the chip?

Comment: If you are going to work with electronics, you really need to learn to look-up and read datasheets: [Datasheet for LM7805](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

No. You definitely can not use LM7805 regulators for this task.

- They are low-voltage DC regulators. They expect, typically, 8 - 20 V DC in.
- YOU NEED ELECTRICAL ISOLATION between the mains and your Arduino. The isolation should be rated to at least 1,000 V.

You need to either use a 230 V relay to monitor each switch or use an opto-isolator with mains dropping resistors. The relay is the safer option in your case. Mount the relays securely and keep all mains wiring away from the Arduino wiring.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGvQ9H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay signalling of mains voltage.*

In this configuration inputs are pulled 'low'. You need to configure internal pull-up resistors in the Arduino.

Judging by your question you have limited knowledge about electricity so I urge extreme caution.

Comment: Using relays is a great idea, but if in case you want to use optocouplers, here is the link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=54024